# filter in a tidygraph

Tags: r, igraph, tidygraph

Consider this simple example

```
library(tidygraph)

mynodes <- tibble(id = c(1,2,3,4,5))

myedges <- tibble(from = c(1,1,1,5),
                  to = c(1,2,3,4),
                  power = c(10,10,10,3))

tbl_graph(nodes = mynodes, edges = myedges)
# A tbl_graph: 5 nodes and 4 edges
#
# A directed multigraph with 2 components
#
# Node Data: 5 x 1 (active)
     id
  <dbl>
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
#
# Edge Data: 4 x 3
   from    to power
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1     1    10
2     1     2    10
3     1     3    10
# ? with 1 more row
```

I know I can use `filter` to easily filter the nodes or the edges.

My problem is how to filter the nodes based on a condition on the edges.

For instance running:

`mygraph %>% activate(edges) %>% filter(power == 3)`

will still returns **all** the nodes, which is annoying when plotting (these nodes will have no edges!).

How can I keep all nodes that are connected with my filtered set of edges?

```
# A tbl_graph: 5 nodes and 1 edges
#
# A rooted forest with 4 trees
#
# Edge Data: 1 x 3 (active)
   from    to power
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1     5     4     3
#
# Node Data: 5 x 1
     id
  <dbl>
1     1
2     2
3     3
# ? with 2 more rows
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is actually a very simple solution

```
activate(nodes) %>% 
  filter(!node_is_isolated())
```

Comment: So, it'd be: `mygraph %>%  activate(edges) %>% filter(power == 3) %>% activate(nodes) %>% filter(!node_is_isolated())`

Comment: @NOOBIE, thanks. can I just graph immediate neighbours of non-isolated nodes using the above code?

Comment: Weird! Thank you for the comment, tidygraph is very particular about the order....first, filter edges, then activate node and filter(!node_is_isolated())....did not work in reverse

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution is to transform your data into `subgraph` and filter it by `id`:

### Create a `subgraph` and `filter` by `id`:

```
sub_mygraph <- to_subgraph(mygraph, id %in% c(4, 5), subset_by = "nodes")$subgraph 

sub_mygraph
# A tbl_graph: 2 nodes and 1 edges
#
# A rooted tree
#
# Node Data: 2 x 1 (active)
     id
  <dbl>
1     4
2     5
#
# Edge Data: 1 x 3
   from    to power
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1     2     1     3
```

Or you can transform your data into `data.frame` and filter it by `power`, and then convert to `tbl_graph` back.

### Convert to `data.frame`:

```
library(tidygraph)

mygraph %>% igraph::as_data_frame() %>% 
  filter(power == 3) %>% 
  as_tbl_graph()

# A tbl_graph: 2 nodes and 1 edges
#
# A rooted tree
#
# Node Data: 2 x 1 (active)
  name 
  <chr>
1 5    
2 4    
#
# Edge Data: 1 x 3
   from    to power
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1     2     3
```

Or you can filter by `id`, but this is not the most straightforward approach because you first have to identify the `id` that're included in `power` 3:

```
mygraph %>% filter(id %in% c(5, 4))

# A tbl_graph: 2 nodes and 1 edges
#
# A rooted tree
#
# Node Data: 2 x 1 (active)
     id
  <dbl>
1     4
2     5
#
# Edge Data: 1 x 3
   from    to power
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1     2     1     3
```

And now you can plot it without the annoying nodes:

```
library(ggraph)

mygraph %>% igraph::as_data_frame() %>% 
  filter(power == 3) %>% 
  as_tbl_graph () %>% 
  rename(id = name) %>% 
  ggraph() +
  geom_edge_fan() +
  geom_node_point(aes(color = id)) +
  theme_graph()
```

[image]

#### Note

Note that convert to `data.frame` will change your `id` variable name, so you can change it again with `rename`.

Comment: interesting thanks! but using `as_data_frame` removes the additional node variables...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .E() & .N() fcns to access nodes or edges while the other is activated in tidygraph

This is mentioned in the intoduction here:
https://www.data-imaginist.com/2017/introducing-tidygraph/

So to filter to nodes based on edge attributes, you can use the .E() function while nodes are activated:

```
mygraph %>%
  activate("nodes") %>%
  filter(.E()$power[id] == 3)
```